# the "|=" operator in c++

Tags: c++, boolean-operations

I have a question about "|=" in c++, how this operator works, for example:

```
bool result;

result |= callFunctionOne(sig);
result |= callFunctionTwo(sig);
result |= callFunctionThree(sig);
result |= callFunctionFour(sig);
```

and the function called above, will reutrn "true" if the paramater sig is processed in the function, otherwish, return "false";

the sig can be processed only in one function each time, how the "`|=`" works?

Comment: That ain't right. You need to initialise `result` to zero.

Comment: It's cleaner to initialize it to `false`. Zero, when cast to `bool` will become `false`, so the net result is the same. But in general it's more readable to initialize variables with literals of the same type: `float x = 0.0f;` etcetera.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`|` is bitwise OR.

`|=` says take what is returned in one of your function and `bitwise OR` it with the `result`, then store it into `result`. It is the equivalent of doing something like:

`result = result | callFunctionOne(sig);`

Taking your code example:

```
bool result;

result |= callFunctionOne(sig);
result |= callFunctionTwo(sig);
result |= callFunctionThree(sig);
result |= callFunctionFour(sig);
```

and your logic of

> will reutrn "true" if the paramater sig is processed in the function,
>   otherwish, return "false";

So that means that if you don't define result, it will be by default **FALSE**.

```
result = false;
```

`callFunctionOne` returns **TRUE**

```
result = result | callFunctionOne;
```

`result` equals **TRUE**.

```
result = false;
```

`callFunctionOne` returns FALSE

```
result = result | callFunctionOne
```

result equals FALSE.

While it may seem that this is a `boolean OR`, it still is using the `bitwise OR` which is essentially `OR'ing` the number `1` or `0`.

So given that `1` is equal to TRUE and `0` is equal to FALSE, remember your truth tables:

```
p   q   p ∨ q
T   T   T
T   F   T
F   T   T
F   F   F
```

Now, since you call each function after another, that means the result of a previous function will ultimately determine the final result from `callFunctionFour`. In that, **three-quarters** of the time, it will be **TRUE** and **one-quarter** of the time, it will be **FALSE**.

Answer (score 2):

`a |= b` is equivalent to `a = a | b`.

Comment: And it's not equivalent to `a = a || b`. So b will be evaluated regardless of the current value of a.

Comment: @Alan: Yep. I think the distinction is easier to make once you realize that TRUE and FALSE are really 1 and 0, then you do the Truth Tables to break it down to see that it is bitwise OR, and not boolean per se.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simple, it will assign `true` to `result` if any of those functions return `true`, and `false` otherwise. But there is one problem - `result` must be `initialized`, otherwise this bit operation will be performed on random initial value and could return `true` even if all of the functions returns `false`.

The operator itself is called ["bitwise inclusive or"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR).

Answer (score -1):

The | operator is bitwise OR (if you know the boolean logic, on a bool variable it acts as a boolean OR). If one or many calls return true, result will be true. If all calls are returning false, the result is false.

Each time, it's the equivalent of result = result | callFunctionXXX(sig);

Remark: in your sample code, the variable result is not initialized. It should be "bool result = false;"

Comment: Well I find your downvote abusive. The operation performed, as the variable is a boolean, is definitely a boolean OR. My answer is clear, short and concise. Technically, the operator is named "bitwise OR", but that would not have helped OP much. I've edited my answer.

Comment: It's a logical inclusive OR operation, which is what the bitwise OR does. Use the truth tables and you'll see that it is a logical disjunction. While boolean OR is similar, don't get tripped up because it says BOOLEAN as the keyword. Taken to the lowest level, it is really 1 and 0. But it's still not BOOLEAN OR nor is there really any concept of that in C++. It has BITWISE OR or short-circuit boolean operators, but not BOOLEAN OR. Just because it says BOOLEAN, does not mean it could be int abc = 1234; and then peform a BITWISE operation on that. Either way, it's not really called a BOOLEAN OR.

Comment: And if you feel my downvote is abusive, then you need to tighten up. Your answer is incomplete as it was at the time of downvoting.

Comment: You need to step back a little and reconsider this whole thing again.

Comment: @Jem:  It's not boolean OR.  Technical precision is important on SO.  Even if you think the technical rigor will not help the OP, it is still important to be rigorous for those who may google this question in the future.

Comment: I agree with you, that's why I fixed it. I plaid guilty, I was more explaining the purpose of the code and did not gave the accurate name of the operator. But people here need to relax, that drama is crazy, and it all looks like a competition. I find the accepted "1 page answer" to this simple question confusing and overkill.

Comment: @Jem:  If you find the accepted answer to be overkill and undesirable, then SO may not be right for you.  The accepted answer is a good example of what is expected here.

Comment: I don't think it's undesirable, but it could be way better.

Comment: Well if it can be way better, I await your better answer. I have even made it Community Wiki now.

Comment: Are you seriously still on that story ? That's ridiculous, you need to tighten up. I won't waste my time to add yet another answer to this just to prove my point.

Comment: Well, then I guess you don't have a better answer.